# how to implement on icon click listener in IconPageIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using `IconPageIndicator` from `viewPagerIndicator` library. when an icon is clicked in the indicator i need the the view pager to move to that page.how can i get the event click when the icon is clicked?
 how can a know which icon is clicked in the `IconPageIndicator`?

Comment: +1...i m going to post my solution.@bill gates

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have read your question and test sample example.you are right It can't move when we click on icons.

so you need to edit library project ---> IconPageIndicator.java

just replace the below method

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged() 
{
    mIconsLayout.removeAllViews();
    IconPagerAdapter iconAdapter = (IconPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
    int count = iconAdapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(getContext(), null, R.attr.vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle);
        view.setImageResource(iconAdapter.getIconResId(i));
        view.setTag(""+i);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int viewPosition = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPosition);
            }
        });
        mIconsLayout.addView(view);
    }
    if (mSelectedIndex > count) {
        mSelectedIndex = count - 1;
    }
    setCurrentItem(mSelectedIndex);
    requestLayout();
}
```

clean the library project and rebuild it.also don't forget to clean and rebuild your project.I hope it will work.

Comment: @bill gates i m glad it helped you.

Comment: hey I am getting an error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator

Comment: @user1051505 can you show me error log?use http://pastie.org/ also do proper cleaning of both project and viewPagerIndicator lib project.

Comment: hey, i got it. I had a problem with my project build path. You saved me a day buddy! :D Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @user1051505 okey..glad it helped..:)

Comment: hey i posted another question in this area. Please have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027718/customize-padding-and-margin-in-iconpageindicator

Comment: I'm using Gradle to inport the library, will this method work for me?

Comment: @Tom Hart sry i don't know.

Comment: @Cully Cross I m glad it helped.. :)