# customize padding and margin in IconPageIndicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to implement a custom IconPageIndicator - viewpager. I want to customize the margins and paddings of the icons displayed in com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator. So I wrote my custom IconPageIndicator and CustomLinearLayout. I changed the dividerPadding variable in CustomLinearLayout. Here is the code. But this doesn't seem to work. The margins and paddings are still the same. Any help?

```
class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private static final int[] LL = new int[] {
        /* 0 */ android.R.attr.divider,
        /* 1 */ android.R.attr.showDividers,
        /* 2 */ android.R.attr.dividerPadding,
    };
    private static final int LL_DIVIDER = 10;
    private static final int LL_SHOW_DIVIDER = 2;
    private static final int LL_DIVIDER_PADDING = 10;

    private Drawable mDivider;
    private int mDividerWidth;
    private int mDividerHeight;
    private int mShowDividers;
    private int mDividerPadding;


    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, int themeAttr) {
        super(context);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null, LL, themeAttr, 0);
        setDividerDrawable(a.getDrawable(CustomLinearLayout.LL_DIVIDER));
        mDividerPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(LL_DIVIDER_PADDING, 0);
        mShowDividers = a.getInteger(LL_SHOW_DIVIDER, SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public void setDividerDrawable(Drawable divider) {
        if (divider == mDivider) {
            return;
        }
        mDivider = divider;
        if (divider != null) {
            mDividerWidth = divider.getIntrinsicWidth();
            mDividerHeight = divider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        } else {
            mDividerWidth = 5;
            mDividerHeight = 5;
        }
        setWillNotDraw(divider == null);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void measureChildWithMargins(View child, int parentWidthMeasureSpec, int widthUsed, int parentHeightMeasureSpec, int heightUsed) {
        final int index = indexOfChild(child);
        final int orientation = getOrientation();
        final LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(index)) {
            if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
                //Account for the divider by pushing everything up
                params.topMargin = 10;
            } else {
                //Account for the divider by pushing everything left
                params.leftMargin = 10;
            }
        }

        final int count = getChildCount();
        if (index == count - 1) {
            if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count)) {
                if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
                    params.bottomMargin = 10;
                } else {
                    params.rightMargin = 10;
                }
            }
        }
        super.measureChildWithMargins(child, parentWidthMeasureSpec, widthUsed, parentHeightMeasureSpec, heightUsed);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mDivider != null) {
            if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL) {
                drawDividersVertical(canvas);
            } else {
                drawDividersHorizontal(canvas);
            }
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void drawDividersVertical(Canvas canvas) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            if (child != null && child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(i)) {
                    final android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                    final int top = child.getTop() - lp.topMargin/* - mDividerHeight*/;
                    drawHorizontalDivider(canvas, top);
                }
            }
        }

        if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count)) {
            final View child = getChildAt(count - 1);
            int bottom = 0;
            if (child == null) {
                bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - mDividerHeight;
            } else {
                //final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                bottom = child.getBottom()/* + lp.bottomMargin*/;
            }
            drawHorizontalDivider(canvas, bottom);
        }
    }

    private void drawDividersHorizontal(Canvas canvas) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            if (child != null && child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(i)) {
                    final android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                    final int left = child.getLeft() - lp.leftMargin/* - mDividerWidth*/;
                    drawVerticalDivider(canvas, left);
                }
            }
        }

        if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count)) {
            final View child = getChildAt(count - 1);
            int right = 0;
            if (child == null) {
                right = getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - mDividerWidth;
            } else {
                //final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                right = child.getRight()/* + lp.rightMargin*/;
            }
            drawVerticalDivider(canvas, right);
        }
    }

    private void drawHorizontalDivider(Canvas canvas, int top) {
        mDivider.setBounds(getPaddingLeft() + mDividerPadding, top,
                getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - mDividerPadding, top + mDividerHeight);
        mDivider.draw(canvas);
    }

    private void drawVerticalDivider(Canvas canvas, int left) {
        mDivider.setBounds(left, getPaddingTop() + mDividerPadding,
                left + mDividerWidth, getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - mDividerPadding);
        mDivider.draw(canvas);
    }

    private boolean hasDividerBeforeChildAt(int childIndex) {
        if (childIndex == 0 || childIndex == getChildCount()) {
          return false;
        }
        if ((mShowDividers & SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE) != 0) {
            boolean hasVisibleViewBefore = false;
            for (int i = childIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (getChildAt(i).getVisibility() != GONE) {
                    hasVisibleViewBefore = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return hasVisibleViewBefore;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class CustomIconPageIndicator extends HorizontalScrollView implements PageIndicator {
    private final CustomLinearLayout mIconsLayout;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private OnPageChangeListener mListener;
    private Runnable mIconSelector;
    private int mSelectedIndex;

    public CustomIconPageIndicator(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomIconPageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        mIconsLayout = new CustomLinearLayout(context, com.viewpagerindicator.R.attr.vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle);
        addView(mIconsLayout, new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));
    }

    private void animateToIcon(final int position) {
        final View iconView = mIconsLayout.getChildAt(position);
        if (mIconSelector != null) {
            removeCallbacks(mIconSelector);
        }
        mIconSelector = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final int scrollPos = iconView.getLeft() - (getWidth() - iconView.getWidth()) / 2;
                smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
                mIconSelector = null;
            }
        };
        post(mIconSelector);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (mIconSelector != null) {
            // Re-post the selector we saved
            post(mIconSelector);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mIconSelector != null) {
            removeCallbacks(mIconSelector);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(arg0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPageScrolled(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        setCurrentItem(arg0);
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPageSelected(arg0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager view) {
        if (mViewPager == view) {
            return;
        }
        if (mViewPager != null) {
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(null);
        }
        PagerAdapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
        }
        mViewPager = view;
        view.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        mIconsLayout.removeAllViews();
        IconPagerAdapter iconAdapter = (IconPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
        int count = iconAdapter.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ImageView view = new ImageView(getContext(), null, com.viewpagerindicator.R.attr.vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle);
            view.setImageResource(iconAdapter.getIconResId(i));
            view.setTag(""+i);
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int viewPosition = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPosition);
                }
            });
            mIconsLayout.addView(view);
        }
        if (mSelectedIndex > count) {
            mSelectedIndex = count - 1;
        }
        setCurrentItem(mSelectedIndex);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager view, int initialPosition) {
        setViewPager(view);
        setCurrentItem(initialPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
        if (mViewPager == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager has not been bound.");
        }
        mSelectedIndex = item;
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item);

        int tabCount = mIconsLayout.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
            View child = mIconsLayout.getChildAt(i);
            boolean isSelected = (i == item);
            child.setSelected(isSelected);
            if (isSelected) {
                animateToIcon(item);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not setting margins correctly in right method.

Go **Library project-->IconPageIndicator** and edit **notifyDataSetChanged() method** as below:

```
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    mIconsLayout.removeAllViews();
    IconPagerAdapter iconAdapter = (IconPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
    int count = iconAdapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(getContext(), null, R.attr.vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(10 , 10, 0 , 0 ); // Here you can set margins.
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

        view.setImageResource(iconAdapter.getIconResId(i));
        view.setTag(""+i);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int viewPosition = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPosition);
            }
        });
        mIconsLayout.addView(view);
    }
    if (mSelectedIndex > count) {
        mSelectedIndex = count - 1;
    }
    setCurrentItem(mSelectedIndex);
    requestLayout();
}
```

don't forget to clean the library project and rebuild it.I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the padding on the drawable itself like this:

indicator.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />

            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and change your adapter to specify the icon resource like this:

```
private class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
    // suppressed other adapter methods
    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int i) {
        return R.drawable.page_indicator;
    }
}
```